# Where do shared class files belong in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm writing a program in C# that has two classes, Foo and Bar. I have two executables that will use them, GenerateFooBar and SearchFooBar. My question is how should my solution be partitioned? From what I can gather, everything can live in one solution and each executable should have it's own project. Should Foo and Bar

- share a project?
- each have their own projects?
- go with one of the other projects?
- something else?

Thanks for the help! I'm coming from Java if that's helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, create project called for example `Common`, and put all your classes and businbes logics there. Set project type as `Class Library`

Next add your other projects and in them `Add Reference` to Solution `Common` project to use it.

[image]

If multiple users are meant to work with the shared library, the best solution will be to create the local nugget

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the references!

Answer (score 1):

Create a shared project and put Foo and Bar into it. Reference that project from both executable projects.

If you later have many developers depending on the shared library you might make it into a Nuget package that you publish and have them depend on that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

> From what I can gather, everything can live in one solution and each
>   executable should have it's own project.

Yes, you are right.

> how should my solution be partitioned?

Totally depends on you and how you would like to manage it.

You could create one project, multiple projects, each separated projects, etc.

But, to reuse code as much as we can and to give a more structured way. Here is what you can do.

Make one Project which will hold the ApplicationServices, Helpers, etc eg: Foo and Bar.

Make Another Project which will hold the application itself (Could be two projects one for search and one for generate). You can add reference of service project to your foo and bar projects and to any other project you create in future.

So in the end you will have 2 or 3 projects (depending on you)

1- ApplicationServices

2- Generators/GeneratorServices/GenerateApplications/anyname

3- Search/SearchServices/SearchApplications/anyname